# How to pre-select radiobutton- / checkbox-group in the playframework?

Tags: java, scala, templates, web, playframework

I am trying to construct a simple form with the Play!Framework 2.3.8. Therefore I have created a radiobutton group, which works fine, but how do you pre-select a certain radiobutton?

I did not find anything for this in the documentation:

[Documentation radiobuttons](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.inputRadioGroup$)

The same problem exists for checkboxes:

[Documentation checkboxes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.inputCheckboxGroup$)

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit(), 'id -> "userForm"){
        <fieldset>
            @helper.inputRadioGroup(
            userForm("Geschlecht"),
            options = options("Mann"->"Mann","Frau"->"Frau"),
            '_label -> "Gender",
            '_error -> userForm("Geschlecht").error.map(_.withMessage("select gender"))
            )
        </fieldset>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are passing form object in view while rendering, that form object must be filled with a instance having selected value of field **Geschlecht**

controller code

```
UserForm user = new UserForm();
//set value of Geschlecht
user.Geschlecht = Mann;

Form<UserForm> form = Form.form(UserForm.class);
form.fill(user)

Html view = views.index.render(userForm);
```

index.scala.html

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit(), 'id -> "userForm"){
        <fieldset>
            @helper.inputRadioGroup(
            userForm("Geschlecht"),
            options = options("Mann"->"Mann","Frau"->"Frau"),
            '_label -> "Gender",
            '_error -> userForm("Geschlecht").error.map(_.withMessage("select gender"))
            )
        </fieldset>
```

in options map, it will select entry with same key as value of field Geschlecht.

Comment: Thank you, had to change my controller but understood the idea. Very usefull hint!